# My variadic templated constructor hides copy constructor, preventing the class to be copied

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I made a `Vector<numType, numberOfCoords>` class. I was happy with it, it's kinda weird but it seemed to work at the start. But I just found out copying the vectors is impossible.

The reason is that to allow the number of coordinates to be a template, there is a templated variadic constructor which expects the right number of coordinates.

This is what it looks like, with the utility math methods removed:

```
template <typename NumType, unsigned char Size>
class Vector
{
public:
  using CoordType = NumType;

  //Vector(const Vector& v) : values(v.values) {}
  //Vector(Vector&& v) : values(std::move(v.values)) {}

  template<typename... NumTypes>
  constexpr Vector(NumTypes&&... vals) : values{ std::forward<NumTypes>(vals)... }
  {
    static_assert(sizeof...(NumTypes) == Size, "You must provide N arguments.");
  }

  Vector(const std::array<NumType, Size>& values) : values(values) {}
  Vector(std::array<NumType, Size>&& values) : values(std::move(values)) {}

  const NumType& operator[](size_t offset) const { return values[offset]; }
  NumType& operator[](size_t offset) { return values[offset]; }
  //Vector& operator=(const Vector& other) { values = other.values; }
  //Vector& operator=(Vector&& other) { values = std::move(other.values); }

  std::array<NumType, Size> values;

};
```

As you can see - now commented out - I did try to implement copy and move and assignment operations manually. It had no effect, the error is always along the lines of:

```
cannot convert ‘Vector<int, 3>’ to ‘int’ in initialization
```

This is because it is still trying to use the variadic constructor, instead of the copy constructor.

Here is a full <s>working</s> broken sample: https://ideone.com/Jz86vP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might:

- SFINAE your variadic constructor, for example:

  ```
  template <typename... NumTypes,
            std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(NumTypes) == Size
                         && std::conjunction<std::is_same<NumType, NumTypes>::value,
                            int> = 0>
  constexpr Vector(NumTypes&&... vals) : values{ std::forward<NumTypes>(vals)... }
  {
  }
  ```

  Note: [`std::conjunction`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) is C++17, but can be done in C++14.
- or prepend a tag:

  ```
  template <typename... NumTypes>
  constexpr Vector(struct SomeTag, NumTypes&&... vals) :
      values{ std::forward<NumTypes>(vals)... }
  {
  }
  ```
- or redesign the class, for example, something like:

  ```
  template <typename T, std::size_t>
  using always_type = T;

  template <typename NumType, typename Seq> class VectorImpl;

  template <typename NumType, std::size_t ... Is>
  class VectorImpl<NumType, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
  {
  public:
    using CoordType = NumType;

    VectorImpl(const VectorImpl&) = default;
    VectorImpl(VectorImpl&&) = default;
    VectorImpl& operator=(const VectorImpl&) = default;
    VectorImpl& operator=(VectorImpl&&) = default;

    constexpr VectorImpl(always_type<NumType, Is>... vals) : values{ std::forward<NumType>(vals)... }
    {
    }

    VectorImpl(const std::array<NumType, sizeof...(Is)>& values) : values(values) {}
    VectorImpl(std::array<NumType, sizeof...(Is)>&& values) : values(std::move(values)) {}

    const NumType& operator[](size_t offset) const { return values[offset]; }
    NumType& operator[](size_t offset) { return values[offset]; }

    std::array<NumType, sizeof...(Is)> values;
  };

  template <typename T, std::size_t N>
  using Vector = VectorImpl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
  ```

  [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a1117586afdede1)

Comment: Making the variadic constructor `explicit` may be an option

Comment: Thanks a lot, the redesign looks really great. But can I just ask what the forward declaration of the template is doing exactly?

Comment: Also, I cannot figure out how to implement a method outside of the class.

Comment: I do partial specialization. So I need to declare the primary template. Implementation outside of the class is as for any template (specialization): `template <typename NumType, std::size_t ... Is> NumType& VectorImpl<NumType, std::index_sequence<Is...>>::operator[](size_t offset) { return values[offset]; }`.